# If $f(2x)=f(x)+f(2), \forall x > 1$ prove that $f$ in increasing

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, monotone-functions

Let $f:(1, +\infty)\to(0,+\infty)$ and $f(2x)=f(x)+f(2), \forall x > 1$. Prove that f is increasing, if $f$ is a strictly monotone function.

I thought maybe I could use proof by contradiction, but I don't know how to do that. I also tried to prove it by showing that  $\forall x_1,x_2 \in (1,+\infty)$ with $x_1<x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ but again dead end. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could I try e.g. $f(2x)-f(x)=f(2) \Rightarrow \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{2x-x}=\frac{f(2)}{x}$ and using the mean value theorem say $f'(ξ)=\frac{f(2)}{x}>0$ so f is increasing?

Comment: You need to assume $f$ is differentiable to use the MVT

Comment: Is $f$ continuous? differentiable? smooth?

Comment: I only know that $f$ is  a strictly monotone function. Thanks for that, I forgot to point it out.

Comment: Then $f$ is strictly decreasing or strictly increasing. Just show it is not decreasing.

Comment: But if f is increasing then define$ g(x) = -f(x)$ so that $g(2x) = g(x)+g(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know $f$ is strictly monotone and positive, note that $f(4) = 2f(2) > f(2)$ so $f$ must be strictly increasing.

Interestingly, $f(x) = a\ln(x)$ is an example for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and it is indeed increasing...

Comment: Unless $f(2)$ is negative...

Comment: @Paul I think it can't be, as $f \to (0, +\infty)$ so he is correct.

Comment: ah yeah, so it is.

Comment: @Paul yes that was exactly the intent... added "and positive" into the answer text to make this explicit

Answer (score 1):

As

$$
f\left(2^{\log_2(2x)}\right)=f\left(2^{\log_2(x)}\right)+f(2)
$$

calling $F(\cdot) = f\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)$ and $z = \log_2 x$ we have the functional recurrence

$$
F(z+1)=F(z)+f(2)
$$

with solution

$$
F(z) = f(2)z + \Phi(z)
$$

with $\Phi(z)$ a generic periodic/constant function with period $1$ and going backwards

$$
f(x) = f(2)\log_2 x + \Phi(\log_2 x)
$$

now to be in accordance with $f(4) = 2f(2)$ we need $\Phi(\log_2 x) = C_0 = 0$ hence

$$
f(x) = f(2)\log_2 x
$$

which is strictly increasing.